# Is it okay to switch between WSL versions whenever I need to?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I just recently installed Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. My only current Distro is Ubuntu and I'm using it for everything I do. I know that WSL 1 is better to handle projects that interact with both Windows and Linux, while WSL 2 is better for projects specific to Linux only.

I might want to switch between the versions depending on what I'm working on, and I would like to if it's safe to continuously change between versions?

Another alternative I found was doing something like:

```
wsl --export Ubuntu ubuntu.tar
wsl --import Ubuntu2 ./Ubuntu2 ubuntu.tar
```

and then setting the version of the second one with `wsl --set-version Ubuntu2 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq) from Microsoft:

> We currently have no plans to deprecate WSL 1. You can run WSL 1 and WSL 2 distros side by side, and can upgrade and downgrade any distro at any time.

That being said, the switch from one to the other is described as a "conversion", so I would suggest have backups of important files when you switch back and forth (generally a good idea anyway).